# Change Google Cloud Compute Permissions after creation

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

We have a Compute Engine instance running that, on creation, was not given write access to Storage. I can't find a way to change this - is there any way to change this without downing the server to clone and change permissions on the creation of the new instance?

Answer (score 1):

The API Lock feature of Compute VMs cannot be updated after the VM has been created.  You have to recreate the VM.